# Php wont run python script properly

Tags: php, python, symfony, process

I am trying to run a python script which will run some Firebase code from php/laravel, and when I do that, I get this error:

```
    Exit Code: 1(General error)

    Working directory: /home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python

    Output:
    ================


    Error Output:
    ================
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/firestore.py", line
    22, in <module>
        from google.cloud import firestore # pylint: disable=import-error,no-name-in-module
        File "/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore.py", line
        18, in <module>
            from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import __version__
            File
            "/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/__init__.py",
            line 17, in <module>
                from pkg_resources import get_distribution
                File
                "/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
                line 35, in <module>
                    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
                        from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
                        File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
                            from pyexpat import *
                            ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:
                            undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt

                            During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

                            Traceback (most recent call last):
                            File "registerUser.py", line 8, in <module>
                                from firebase_admin import firestore
                                File
                                "/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/firestore.py",
                                line 28, in <module>
                                    raise ImportError('Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make
                                    sure '
                                    ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure
                                    to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module.
```

The same file, when run from terminal, does its job without hickup. Here is php code i use to run it:

```
$data = json_encode(['id' => $id, 'username' => $username]);
    $process = new Process(["venv/bin/python", "registerUser.py", $data], base_path() . "/python");
    $process->run();
    // executes after the command finishes
    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    } else {
        return [
            "success" => true,
            "message" => $process->getOutput()
        ];
    }
```

I tried writing absolute path to venv python, but it did not work. I changed permision of all files and folder to 777. I tried reinstaling "google-cloud-firestore". Nothing works.

here is my python script:

```
# registerUser.py
# !/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/bin/python
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('Firebase.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

doc_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(u'alovelace')
doc_ref.set({
  u'first': u'Ada',
  u'last': u'Lovelace',
  u'born': 1815
})
```

Comment: add following code at the beginning of the file:
`import sys ; fout=open("/tmp/debugdata", "w") ; fout.write(sys.executable + "\n") ; fout.write("\n".join(sys.path) + "\n") ; close(fout)`

run once from your shell, save the file `/tmp/debugdata` under a different name, run then with php and compare the saved file with /tmp/debugdata

Comment: @gelonida completely identical files:

/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/bin/python
/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python
/usr/lib/python37.zip
/usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg
/home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg

Comment: please execute following code from command line
`python -c "import firebase_admin as m ; print(m.__file__)"`
Perhaps this shows something funny. In any case, just post the answer.

Please dump also for both (writing to a temp file as in my first comment) the value of
`"\n".join(sys.argv)+"\n"`

Comment: @gelonida /home/pho7on/projects/php/icy/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/__init__.py

Comment: Doesn't look too funny to me :-( . pls dump `sys.argv for both cases and compare`

Comment: @gelonida i did this: print(str(sys.argv[:1])), and the output in both cases was: ['registerUser.py']

Comment: strange. `sys.argv[:2]` shhould be the absolute path of the python executable + 'registerUser.py'

But so far nothing conclusive